# STM32IDE & DC Motor - Tracking Motor rotation

Tags: stm32, motor, dc-motor, proteus

Is there a way for a microcontroller (STM32) to track DC motor rotation?
Currently in class supposed to connect a DC motor of our choosing to a microcontroller, rotate it by 5 degrees and track the rotation (just the end of the rotation, i.e from 0 to 5 and not 0.1,0.2...) and further use that information. We have not been thought how to do that and I've only seen videos of motor connecting to MC for voltage purposes and not tracking.

Comment: Use a rotary encoder.

Comment: If you can attach magnet to the motor shaft, you can use modern very precise angle sensors like MPS MA782. Alternative you can use standard hall sensors which are integrated for example in Infineon TLE4966K, but this need more advanced "magnetic layout scheme".